# How to upload variable as property name inside firebase database using javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a student management website and inside the database a want upload nameoftheuser : rollnumberoftheuser.

```
var uniUserSem = firebase.database().ref().child("universal/" + FormDetails['sem'].value);
  var uniUserRef = uniUserSem.child("user");
  var uNAME = FormDetails['name'].value;
  uniUserRef.set({
      uNAME : FormDetails['roll'].value,
  })
  window.alert("data uploaded successfully");
  window.open("dashboard.html", "_self");
```

as you can see in the code uNAME contains name of the user and FormDetails['roll'].value contains the roll number of the user. I want to set uNAME as property and roll number(FormDetails['roll'].value) as property value but not able to do so , so please help me , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this, is to use `[]` notation in your `set` call:

```
  uniUserRef.set({
      [uNAME] : FormDetails['roll'].value,
  })
```

Comment: Thank you very much